# How to get %mine vs %remote in the merge tool when dealing with a merge conflict in git?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge-conflict

**Current behavior :**

Git does a good job of automatically merging changes.
When it doesn't, it creates following file : `.base`, `.remote`, `.local` and `.merged`  and we need to manually resolve the conflict in file `.merge`.
Unfortunately, git has already merged the file and added `<<<<<<<< ======== >>>>>>>' where it couldn't merge automatically.
This is useful when there is less than 5 lines in the conflict, but it is cumbersome otherwise.

**Desired behavior:**

I would like if `.remote` could automatically overwrite `.merge`. Thereby, my merge tool could open `.local` vs `.merged` and I could manually apply all my change in `.merged`. Is it possible to setup this? I'm using tortoise git by the way.

**Why I want this :**

- Since I know what I've changed, there is less chances of mistakes.
- In case of a mistake, the code not merged is likely to me mine not others.
- Simple two file comparison when merging instead of three/four
- Used this with another source control and liked it a lot.

Of course I could write a program to do this for me, but would prefer not to if it's already possible otherwise.

Comment: GIt *doesn't* create all those files during a merge conflict. It's your GUI (in this case TortoiseGit) that creates them. The underlying Git code leaves the three input files (base, local/--ours, and remote/--theirs) in the *index* and writes the conflict marker variants in the work-tree file. This doesn't change the *problem* that you are facing, but it changes where you should seek answers. (I don't use TortoiseGit so have no further advice.)

Comment: most known tools already have working integration with git, you should only find out how to set up yours